# SQL NOOB - Oracle joins and Row Number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I was hoping to get some guidance on a SQL script I am trying to put together for Oracle database 11g.

I am attempting to perform a count of claims from the 'claim' table, and order them by year / month / and enterprise.

I was able to get a count of claims and order them like I would like, however I need to pull data from another table and I am having trouble combining the 'row_number' function with a join.

Here is my script so far:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
     TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM') MONTH,
     ENTERPRISE_IID,
     COUNT (*) CLAIMS
FROM (SELECT CLAIM.CLAIM_EID,
    CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE,
    CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CLAIM.CLAIM_EID, CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID
    ORDER BY CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE DESC) RN
        FROM CLAIM
        WHERE CLAIM_IID IN (SELECT DISTINCT (CLAIM_IID)
            FROM CLAIM_LINE
            WHERE STATUS <> 'D')
            AND CLAIM.CONTEXT = '1'
            AND CLAIM.CLAIM_STATUS = 'A'
            AND CLAIM.LAST_ANALYSIS_DATE IS NOT NULL)
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP ENTERPRISE_IID,
TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY'),
TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM');
```

So far all of my data is coming from the 'claim' table. This pulls the following result:

```
YEAR MONTH ENTERPRISE_IID     CLAIMS
---- ----- -------------- ----------
2016 01                 6          1
2015 08                 6          3
2016 02                 6          2
2015 09                 6          2
2015 07                 6          2
2015 09                 5         22
2015 11                 5         29
2015 12                 5         27
2016 04                 5          8
2015 07                 5         29
2015 05                 5         15
2015 06                 5          5
2015 10                 5         45
2016 03                 5         54
2015 03                 5         10
2016 02                 5         70
2016 01                 5         55
2015 08                 5         32
2015 04                 5         12

19 rows selected.
```

The enterprise_IID is the primary key on the 'enterprise' table. The 'enterprise' table also contains the 'name' attribute for each entry. I would like to join the claim and enterprise table in order to show the enterprise name for this count, and not the enterprise_IID.

As you can tell I am rather new to Oracle and SQL, and I am a bit stuck on this one. I was thinking that I should do an inner join between the two tables, but I am not quite sure how to do that when using the row_number function.

Or perhaps I am taking the wrong approach here, and someone could push me in another direction.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
    TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM') MONTH,
    ENTERPRISE_IID,
    ENTERPRISE.NAME,
    COUNT (*) CLAIMS
FROM (SELECT CLAIM.CLAIM_EID,
    CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE,
    CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CLAIM.CLAIM_EID, CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID
    ORDER BY CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE DESC) RN
        FROM CLAIM, enterprise
        INNER JOIN ENTERPRISE
        ON CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID = ENTERPRISE.ENTERPRISE_IID
        WHERE CLAIM_IID IN (SELECT DISTINCT (CLAIM_IID)
            FROM CLAIM_LINE
            WHERE STATUS <> 'D')
            AND CLAIM.CONTEXT = '1'
            AND CLAIM.CLAIM_STATUS = 'A'
            AND CLAIM.LAST_ANALYSIS_DATE IS NOT NULL)
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY ENTERPRISE.NAME,
ENTERPRISE_IID,
TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY'),
TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM');
```

Thank you in advance!

"Desired Output"

```
YEAR MONTH NAME     CLAIMS
---- ----- ---- ----------
2016 01    Ent1        1
2015 08    Ent1        3
2016 02    Ent1        2
2015 09    Ent1        2
2015 07    Ent1        2
2015 09    Ent2       22
2015 11    Ent2       29
2015 12    Ent2       27
2016 04    Ent2        8
2015 07    Ent2       29
2015 05    Ent2       15
2015 06    Ent2        5
2015 10    Ent2       45
2016 03    Ent2       54
2015 03    Ent2       10
2016 02    Ent2       70
2016 01    Ent2       55
2015 08    Ent2       32
2015 04    Ent2       12

19 rows selected.
```

Comment: Please, describe more clearly what you want to achieve with this query. Providing sample data and required results will help us a lot.

Comment: Hi,  As you are seeing from the solutions offered to you, "row number" has no relationship to the join with your "master" (ENTERPRISE) table. I also don't understand why you need row_number() in what you have written so far; it seems for each combination (CLAIM_EID, ENTERPRISE_IID) you are just selecting the most recent date verifying the conditions? That is much easier to do than what you have written. Also, as OldProgrammer has shown, use EXTRACT (YEAR FROM...) and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ...), not the TO_CHAR you used.

Comment: Thanks Mathguy, this is all very useful to me as a noob. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Joins can be used when calculating row numbers with `row_number` function.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
    TO_CHAR (SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM') MONTH,
    ENTERPRISE_IID,
    NAME,
    COUNT (*) CLAIMS
FROM (SELECT CLAIM.CLAIM_EID,
      CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE,
      CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID,
      ENTERPRISE.NAME,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CLAIM.CLAIM_EID, CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID
      ORDER BY CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE DESC) RN
      FROM CLAIM --, enterprise (this is not required as the table is being joined already)
      INNER JOIN ENTERPRISE ON CLAIM.ENTERPRISE_IID = ENTERPRISE.ENTERPRISE_IID
      INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CLAIM_IID FROM CLAIM_LINE WHERE STATUS <> 'D') CLAIM_LINE 
      ON CLAIM.CLAIM_IID = CLAIM_LINE.CLAIM_IID
      WHERE CLAIM.CONTEXT = '1'
      AND CLAIM.CLAIM_STATUS = 'A'
      AND CLAIM.LAST_ANALYSIS_DATE IS NOT NULL) t
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY NAME, --ENTERPRISE.NAME (The alias ENTERPRISE is not accessible here.)
ENTERPRISE_IID,
TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'YYYY'),
TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE, 'MM');
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns the same error as my second attempt script - Error at line 19
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier - I am curious why name is an invalid identifier when you are joining enterprise in the from statement? I know I am missing something here.. Thank you again for the help!!

Comment: check the edited version. i selected the name in the inner query.you would not get the error now. Even though you are joining the `enterprise` table, you have to `select` the column for it to be visible to the outer `select`.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so much. Now I will try to reverse engineer what you did and hopefully learn :) THANK YOU!!

Comment: sure..you were almost there with the query you had. I am sure you will get better fast.

Comment: My personal preference would be to get the "latest" system_entry_date with MAX aggregate and GROUP BY, instead of evaluating the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function and doing an = 1 equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Just hypothesis to start with, because requirement of query output unclear:

```
  SELECT 
    C.ENTERPRISE_IID, 
    E.ENTERPRISE_NAME,
    extract(year from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE) SYSTEM_ENTRY_YEAR,
    extract(month from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE) SYSTEM_ENTRY_MONTH,
    count(distinct C.CLAIM_EID) CLAIM_COUNT
  FROM 
    CLAIM      C, 
    ENTERPRISE E
  WHERE 
    C.CLAIM_IID IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT (CLAIM_IID)
      FROM CLAIM_LINE
      WHERE STATUS <> 'D'
    )
    AND C.CONTEXT = '1'
    AND C.CLAIM_STATUS = 'A'
    AND C.LAST_ANALYSIS_DATE IS NOT NULL
    AND E.ENTERPRISE_IID = C.ENTERPRISE_IID
  GROUP BY
    C.ENTERPRISE_IID, 
    E.ENTERPRISE_NAME,
    extract(year from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE),
    extract(month from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE) 
  ORDER BY
    extract(year from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE),
    extract(month from CLAIM.SYSTEM_ENTRY_DATE), 
    E.ENTERPRISE_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns an Error at line 4
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. The script appears much more concise and efficient than my logic. The FROM appears to be in the right place, im not sure why it is throwing this error?

Comment: Also, to clarify on the output, i added a "desired output" portion to my post. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a comma after `E.ENTERPRISE_NAME` (now corrected). Without sample data tables I can't test a query ...

Comment: Hi ThinkJet. Thank you for your comments, I hope I did not come off sounding entitled when mentioning the error i was running into. I know it can be difficult / impossible with limited information. I really appreciate your input, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write the query like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(c.system_entry_date,'MM'),'YYYY') AS year
     , TO_CHAR(TRUNC(c.system_entry_date,'MM'),'MM')   AS month
     , e.enterprise_name                               AS name 
     , COUNT(*)                                        AS claims
  FROM (
         SELECT r.claim_eid
              , r.enterprise_iid
              , MAX(r.system_entry_date) AS system_entry_date
           FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT l.claim_iid
                    FROM claim_line l
                   WHERE l.status <> 'D'
                ) d
           JOIN claim r
             ON r.claim_iid = d.claim_iid
            AND r.context = '1'
            AND r.claim_status = 'A'
            AND r.last_analysis_date IS NOT NULL
          GROUP
             BY r.claim_eid
              , r.enterprise_iid
       ) c
  JOIN enterprise e
    ON e.enterprise_iid = c.enterprise_iid
 GROUP
    BY c.enterprise_iid
     , TRUNC(c.system_entry_date,'MM')
     , e.enterprise_name
 ORDER
    BY e.enterprise_name
     , TRUNC(c.system_entry_date,'MM')
```

A few notes:

I prefer to qualify *ALL* column references with the table name or short table alias, and assign aliases to all inline views.

Since the usage of ROW_NUMBER() appears to be get the "latest" system_entry_date for a claim and eliminate duplicates, I'd prefer to use a GROUP BY and a MAX() aggregate.

I prefer to use a join operation rather than the NOT IN (subquery) pattern. (Or, I would tend to use a NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery) pattern.

I don't think it matters too much if you use TO_CHAR or EXTRACT. The TO_CHAR gets you the leading zero in the month, I don't think EXTRACT(MONTH ) gets you the leading zero. I'd use whichever gets me closest to the resultset I need.Personally, I would return just a single column, either containing the year and month as one string e.g. TO_CHAR( , 'YYYYMM') or just a DATE value. It all depends what I'm going to be doing with that.

Comment: Thank you so much. This gives me a lot to learn from, much appreciated.